# What are the state-of-art methods for solving functional equations?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, equation, solver, lambda-calculus

Suppose that you want to find a λ-calculus program, `T`, that satisfies the following equations:

```
(T (λ f x . x))            = (λ a t . a)
(T (λ f x . (f x)))        = (λ a t . (t a))
(T (λ f x . (f (f x))))    = (λ a b t . (t a b))
(T (λ f x . (f (f (f x)))) = (λ a b c t . (t a b c))
```

On this case, I've manually found this solution:

```
T = (λ t . (t (λ b c d . (b (λ e . (c e d)))) (λ b . b) (λ b . b)))
```

Is there any strategy for solving such λ-calculus equations automatically? What is the state of art on that subject?

Comment: What notion of equality are you using here?

Comment: [Computational equality](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/equality)*. Please read `a = b` as `a` beta reduces to `b`, in strong normal form.

Comment: While I find your question interesting I do not think this is a good fit for Stack Overflow. If you are asking about algorithms you should ask on [computer science.SE]. As it stands your question doesn't seem about programming but about algorithm design and it's too broad to be answered on SO (a definite answer to your question would be a book/sets of books).

Comment: I didn't know where to post, book suggestions are really welcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, [higher order unification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unification_%28computer_science%29#Higher-order_unification) is undecidable, so you can't hope for a general procedure for finding solutions to these kinds of equations.

There has been a significant amount of work on finding solutions to such problems, but I don't know of any that gives the answer to your particular problem. Some good references are summarized in this answer: [Higher-order unification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1936432/higher-order-unification)

Answer (score 9):

I'm not sure about state of the art, but William E Byrd's work on relational interpreters (such as [this paper](http://webyrd.net/quines/quines.pdf)) allows program synthesis of this kind.

Also see his [PolyConf talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eQL48qYDwp4) for some neat stuff on searching for program terms. Your examples seem like they would be fairly easy to express in that way.